# PDF corrupt image output

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have a neat HTML page to output this as a PDF. The HTML page appears in the browser as it should

[image: HTML View]

But when I do `window.print()` this structure looks broken

[image: Print appearance]

My HTML codes are like this

```
<div class="main"> <!-- PDF Page 1 --> </div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
<div class="main"> <!-- PDF Page 2 --> </div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
<!-- more ... -->
```

I spent all day trying to solve this problem. However, I couldn't figure out what was causing it. The red boxes in the corners of the PDF pages have the property `position: absolute;`. The part that overflows from the page is the rest of these pieces. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please put a runnable snippet into your question so we can see the problem. This looks like a CSS related problem but you have provided no CSS. This link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example should help you create a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information like the CSS on the parent element but I think your problem here is the dimensions. You should try by fixing the parent element to take the whole width and height of the viewport.
Maybe like this :

```
<div class="main" style="height:100vh;"> <!-- PDF Page 1 --> </div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
<div class="main" style="height:100vh;"> <!-- PDF Page 2 --> </div>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
<!-- more ... -->
```

Comment: I tried the solution you wrote but it didn't work. There are more red boxes and I do `overflow: hidden` when it overflows from the `.main` tag. still there is an overflow in the PDF output. You can see the application here https://egitim.denakademi.com.tr/admin-paneli/rapor-olustur?egitim_id=341

Comment: Try on put a snippet with your CSS and all, we can't help you like that